# 3B crashes randomly

Tags: pi-3, crash

I've had a random crash occur 2 times now, and I have no idea what is causing them. The last one happened just now, and the pi has been running great for a week (without reboots). The first crash occurred after about 6 hours after the last reboot. I have extracted this from the syslogs. Maybe the router advertisements have something to do with it?

```
Dec 28 12:17:01 raspberrypi CRON[34132]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
Dec 28 12:17:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[588]: eth0: Router Advertisement from fe80::ae22:5ff:fe5b:2784
Dec 28 12:17:43 raspberrypi dhcpcd[588]: eth0: no global addresses for default route
Dec 28 12:19:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[588]: eth0: Router Advertisement from fe80::ae22:5ff:fe5b:2784
Dec 28 12:19:14 raspberrypi dhcpcd[588]: eth0: no global addresses for default route
Dec 28 12:20:16 raspberrypi dhcpcd[588]: eth0: Router Advertisement from fe80::ae22:5ff:fe5b:2784
Dec 28 12:20:16 raspberrypi dhcpcd[588]: eth0: no global addresses for default route
Dec 28 12:22:16 raspberrypi dhcpcd[588]: eth0: Router Advertisement from fe80::ae22:5ff:fe5b:2784
Dec 28 12:22:16 raspberrypi dhcpcd[588]: eth0: no global addresses for default route
Dec 28 12:17:07 raspberrypi fake-hwclock[135]: Wed 28 Dec 12:17:01 UTC 2022
Dec 28 12:17:07 raspberrypi systemd-fsck[153]: e2fsck 1.46.2 (28-Feb-2021)
Dec 28 12:17:07 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0000000000 [0x410fd034]
```

I am running PI os lite 64 bit, storage is on a USB instead of an SD card and ethernet only (wifi is not disabled). Running a nodejs and redis server.

Comment: to be clear ... the first "crash" happened 6 hours after a boot, and the second one a week after the last boot?

Comment: Yes. To me it looks like the whole pi just freezes randomly.